# Adding Setinterval and clear interval to my query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a counter where in member can add or remove his number which gets saved in mysql.

i am using the following jquery/ajax to call the function when member clicks on adding or removing. But sometimes removing does not give the exact count, am planning to use setinterval and clearinterval. And also I need to use set interval once, for example, it should query the file only once with in 5 seconds or exact 5 seconds. but below setinterval and clearinterval does not seem to work,

```
$(function () {
    var checkit = function () {
        $(".addid").click(function () {
            var add_id = $(this).attr("id");
            var dataString = 'add_id=' + add_id;
            $(".add_show" + add_id).fadeIn(400).html('Updating...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "num_check.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $(".add_show" + add_id).html(html);
                    window.clearInterval(nre);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
    var nre = setInterval(checkit, 5000);
});
```

Advise and help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Ajax call as -

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "num_check.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            async : false,
            success: function (html) {
                $(".add_show" + add_id).html(html);
                window.clearInterval(nre);
            }
        });
```

With this, the next Ajax call will not start until the current one has been completed. It should do the trick.

Comment: it worked for the first time, when i came back to the page from a different page, it stopped working. I cant understand, whats wrong in the code. For adding its showing properly, whereas when i delete it then the count shows the old one.